# how to connect the methods to each other like in my code when the user press 2 it will have to go to snack but instead it runs the code to meals java

Tags: java, methods

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class MP3
{
```

//this is the main code that I need to connect each method to each method.
//so that if the user press 2 it will go to snacks but even if you press two now it just continues the code and go-to meals.
//how can I make it so that the user can choose which menu he/she likes to go through?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        int Options_Snacks;
        int Options_Snacks2;
        int Options_Snacks3;
        int Options_Drinks;
        int Options_Drinks2;
        int Options_Drinks3;
        int diff,prod ;
        int yes = 1;
        int no = 2;
        int End;
        
        
        do {
        mainmenu();
        mainmeals(); 
        mainsnacks();
       
        Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Would you like to order more: press " + yes +" for yes and " + no +" for no");
        End = myInput.nextInt();
        
        } while(End == 1);
      }
```

// this code runs smoothly but the other menus don't run when the user press the number instead it runs all the code within the while loop.

```
 public static void mainmenu()
        {
    
        int Orders;
        int Meals = 1;
        int Snacks = 2;
        int Drinks = 3;
        int EXIT = 4;
    
        Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("=======[STRESSFOOD]=====");
        System.out.println("---------[ Menu ]-------");
        System.out.println("1----------Meals--------");
        System.out.println("2---------Snacks--------");
        System.out.println("3---------Drinks--------");
        System.out.println("4--------[ EXIT ]-------");
        Orders = myInput.nextInt();
    
       
       }
    [here's the code I didn't get all in the picture][1]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following implementation:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        openMenu();
}
```

With the while loop in the menu function :

```java
private static void openMenu() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {

            System.out.println("1) Meals");
            System.out.println("2) Snacks");
            System.out.println("3) Drinks");
            System.out.println("4) Exit");
            System.out.print("Your choice ? ");

            switch (scan.nextInt()) {
                case 1:
                    openMealsMenu();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    openSnacksMenu();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    openDrinksMenu();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    scan.close();
                    return;
                default:
                    System.out.println("This is not a valid choice");
            }
        } while (true);

    }
```

Note that you should only use one scanner in your application. If you need your scanner in the openMealsMenu() for example, pass it as a parameter of the method, or just declare a static scanner in your MP3 class since your methods are in the same class.

By the way, by convention, variables should start with a lowercase letter and do not take a `_` (ie. `Options_Drinks3` becomes `optionsDrinks3`).